# What are the singular points of $z/z$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I'm trying to understand what happens when you have on point that can evident can be both.
Or for example $z/z^2$ or $z^2/z$.

Any examples that can clarify this for me?

Comment: 1 minute. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both functions have $0$ as a singularity, since you can't evaluate $0/0$. On the other hand, $0$ is a removable singularity because for every $z\in\mathbb C\backslash\{0\}$, $z^2/z=z$ and $z\mapsto z$ is defined and holomorphic over all $\mathbb C$.

Comment: You are right, Check this mad scientist http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Singularity.html

Comment: @MariaGuthier [Yay!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYvhhMjW32k)

Comment: "Isolated singularity" refers to something entirely different from being removable.

Comment: @Did Yes you're right! Sorry for the confusion. I'll correct it.